# Is this an upper bound or lower bound?

Tags: probability, inequality, logic

I came across a probability distribution function in my work, it is however difficult to find in closed form, therefore I am looking to either upper bound or lower bound it.

Assuming $a,b,T$ are non-negative constants, and $X>0,Y>0$ are Random variables .

What is the direction of the inequality below?

$$\mathbb{P}\left( a \ X + b \ Y \geq T\right) \stackrel{\leq}{\geq} \mathbb{P}\left(  X +  Y \geq \frac{T}{a+b}\right)  $$

i.e am I upper bounding or lower bounding ?

The reason I am doing that is because the distribution of $a X+bY $ is not easy to derive but it is with $X+Y$..

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like $\geq$ since everything is nonnegative.

Comment: Thank Jihad, I understand your point however I still don't have a good reasoning.. @Jihad

Comment: @Jihad I have edited the question to make it more obvious, in this case I think you have to change the sign on inequality in your comment, sorry about that...

Comment: Ok, I think it can be in both directions. If $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative then it is obvious. The interesting case when one of them is positive and the second one is negative for instance.

Comment: Thanks, Jihad I do have that everything is non-negative, so you are saying there is no definite direction? @Jihad

Comment: Wait, if $X$ and $Y$ are both nonnegative then there is an obvious direction.

Comment: do you mind telling me what it is @Jihad? Thanks

Comment: $\leq$ since you can divide left inequality by $(a+b)$.

Comment: if you divde by $a+b$ you dont end up with $X+Y $ but $\frac {aX+bY}{a+b}$.... this is why I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we multiply $X + Y \ge \frac T{a+b}$ by $a+b$ we get $aX + bX + aY + bY \ge T$  This will be more likely to be true than $aX+bY \ge T$ because we are adding positive terms to the left. So in your question the sign should be $\lt$

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand what you mean by " this will be more likely to be true.."  Do you mean I can't tell where it is an upperbound or lower bound?

Comment: You are comparing two probabilities.  Every time the left side in your question is true, the right side is true, but there will presumably be times when the left side is false but the extra terms $bX+aY$ in the way I express it make he right side true.  This means the right side is an upper bound for the left.

Comment: If you don't mind I would like to ask you a question regarding this, I totally understand your answer provided here, but what if $a=b=T=1$ then the inequality is not correct, how come it doesn't hold?

Comment: The inequality of the probabilities is still correct in that case.  We then have $\Bbb P(x+y\ge T) \lt Bbb P(x+y \ge \frac T2)$  The right will be true all the time the left is, and as well when $\frac T2 \le x+y \lt T$

Comment: if $X=Y=4/9$ and $a=T=b=1$ does the inequality hold?

Comment: Absolutely.  In that case $X+Y \ge T$ fails and $X+Y\ge \frac T2$ succeeds.  Remember the $\Bbb P$\s are probabilities and $X,Y$ are random variables.   What I have shown is that the right side event is true every time the left side event, and some others besides.  This is an example.  I have clearly not understood what you are looking for in this series.